# Осталось или остались несколько часов?

Tags: окончания

— Позади осталось несколько часов.

— Несколько часов осталось позади.

Осталось или остались?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Осталось" и там и там. Здесь количество, а не каждый час оставался по-своему. Часы одинаковые (60 минут).

*Несколько человек остались в том здании.* || Здесь допустимо "остались", если они оставались по отдельности.
Это в пункте 3):
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo

И такое правило:
Согласование сказуемого при обозначении подлежащим приблизительного количества. При подлежащем – количественном сочетании со значением приблизительности предпочитается форма единственного числа сказуемого: *Откроется **несколько** новых школ. На земле живет более трех миллиардов людей.* Но: *Лишь несколько студентов смогли решить эту задачу*; форма множественного числа сказуемого обусловлена  «активностью» действующих лиц, названных подлежащим.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!