# Пару(а) минут прошло(и). Лежало(и) тысячу(а) рублей

Tags: числительные

у [oleedd](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472535) в комментариях встретил, что можно и так и так. Как обосновать?

Comment: Здесь немного обсуждали: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472487

Comment: Про глагол во множественном вообще ничего не говорил, но во втором примере звучит (а в первом вообще нет).

Comment: А запятая не нужна между "И ТАК" и "И ТАК"?

Comment: Я не ставлю запятые там, где они очевидны. Это же и так понятно, а тогда зачем лишний раз себя утруждать ;)

Comment: Здесь "пару" выступает наречием и равносильно "несколько" (*— Сколько минут прошло? — Пару.*), а вот что делать с "тысячу" — пока не знаю.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Comment: Напишу в качестве дополнения. У меня был немного похожий вопрос, где oleedd дал ответ с обоснованием: https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/472063/200257

Comment: @Theej Множественное используется, когда говорят о людях. Но "*лежали тысячу рублей*" звучит, скорее всего, это из-за "*лежали деньги*".

Comment: @oleedd понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Родительный падеж и его деления... В школе не дают такого знания.
Пар**у** минут прошл**и**. Не минуты длились, а мы что-то делали в этом отрезке времени, мол: вытерпели пару минут или прошли пару минут молча.
Пар**у** минут прошл**о**. Родительный падеж - пару/пара. Пару - сколько (количество). Пара - какая-то (качество). Пару минут прошло - указание на количество минут.
Пар**а** минут прошл**о** и пар**а** минут прошл**и** - а здесь уже крутота с уклоном на глаголы, а не падежи: "прошло" и "прошли"...